# PySide2: How to embed HTML5 video in QWebEngineView

Tags: python, html, html5-video, pyside2, qtwebengine

I am trying to display a video file inside a PySide2 app I'm writing. That app uses a **QWebEngineView** and loads a **local html file** that contains a **`<video>` tag**, pointing to a local mov or mp4 file. Somehow I can see the player, but it doesn't load the file.

I've put this little html test page together which loads fine in Chrome, but not in my app. Note that in this file I'm using an online mp4 file, but I've tried both, local and online files, mov and mp4.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="https://archive.org/download/VideoTestFiles/1280X72025FpsPhotoJpeg75.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    </video>
</body>
```

In my PySide2 app, I'm loading the page like follows:

```
import os, sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

view = QWebEngineView()

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "test.html")
view.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(path))

view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have also tried the following settings, none of which seem to help:

```
view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.AllowRunningInsecureContent, True)
view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, True)
view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
```

Any help appreciated!

---

**Edit:**

I just realized: while there is no error in Chrome console, there is an error being displayed in the Python console after closing the app:

```
[9476:13164:1017/182854.157:ERROR:media_internals.cc(102)] Cannot get RenderProcessHost
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#audio-and-video-codecs), you must compile Qt WebEngine by enabling the flag -webengine-proprietary-codecs that probably the binaries offered by PySide2 have not enabled.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc ! I don't have the time right now to get into compiling PySide from source, so will have to skip this for the time being and use an external player.